# sending eloquent object to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass Laravel eloquent object to JavaScript function. I have this code:

```
                @php
                    {{$count = 1;}}
                @endphp
                @foreach($user_infos as $info)
                    <tr onclick="">
                        <th scope="row">{{$count++}}</th>
                        <td hidden>{{$info->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info->workplace_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$info->department_name}}</td>
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square" onclick="showPopUp({{$info}})"
                               style="cursor: pointer; color: blue"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

I want to pass the current object ($info) to the function (showPopUp).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

You can use blades @json directive:

```
onclick="showPopUp(@json($info))"
```

Comment: Are you sure, the curly braces are needed? oO

Comment: @shaedrich No, I've just copied the original code and added the directive. thanks for mentioning it, edited.